# Decrease number of x-axis ticks (labels) in barchart

Tags: r, bar-chart, lattice

I am using barchart from the lattice package.  I have time series data going back 10 years, and I would like the x-axis to be displayed in the format %b-%Y, in six month intervals.  This is trivially accomplished in xyplot (given vector of dates DateVector) with syntax such as:

```
scales=list(x=list(format = "%b-%Y",tick.number = length(DateVector)/2))
```

barchart ignores the tick.number option for factors by design, however, so the x axis becomes unreadable for large number of data labels.  How can I reduce the number of ticks and/or tick labels?

Here is a simple example that reproduces my problem, with data following (save the data as Testrr.csv to run, apologies if this is the wrong format, it's my first time ;)

```
library(lattice)

inptTrans <- read.csv("Testrr.csv")
inptTrans$NotherTime <- as.Date(as.character(inptTrans$TransDateS),"%m/%d/%Y")
xyp2 <- barchart (NumE+NumF~ NotherTime, data=inptTrans, main = sprintf("Total")
                  ,type='r',xlab = '',ylab='',col=c('red','black')
                  ,horizontal=FALSE
                  ,scales=list(x=list( rot=45,cex=1.0 ,
                                 labels=format(inptTrans$NotherTime,"%b-%Y"),tick.number=2)
                     )
                  ,key=list(text = list(c("Num F","Num E"))
                     ,rectangle=list(col=c('black','red') ),columns = 2
                     ,corner = c(0.05,-0.11),lty = c(1),lwd=3)
                  ,stack=TRUE
                  )

png(sprintf('Testrr.png'),width = 900, height = 750)
print(xyp2) 
dev.off()
```

Testrr.csv:

```
TransDateS,NumTot,NumF,NumE
01/15/2003,339486,18478,293879
02/15/2003,343761,16430,295272
03/15/2003,413700,17924,356004
04/15/2003,432741,18260,377046
05/15/2003,465439,18721,406632
06/15/2003,490699,18276,424773
07/15/2003,507818,18354,440237
08/15/2003,506530,17391,437386
09/15/2003,481039,17809,411568
10/15/2003,483364,19507,412902
11/15/2003,392189,16308,329675
12/15/2003,444249,18342,367489
01/15/2004,364662,20009,308456
02/15/2004,389718,16894,329946
03/15/2004,511386,20207,434052
04/15/2004,525563,19867,452646
05/15/2004,538570,17557,463289
06/15/2004,620868,20386,535523
07/15/2004,581368,20844,500511
08/15/2004,580773,19687,495930
09/15/2004,523992,21322,442304
10/15/2004,507288,18907,427265
11/15/2004,489571,19135,409818
12/15/2004,510904,21213,419328
01/15/2005,419417,21930,351257
02/15/2005,446402,19600,374778
03/15/2005,581109,22655,486727
04/15/2005,574275,21263,487661
05/15/2005,617399,21033,524466
06/15/2005,688876,26999,584782
07/15/2005,610606,20712,516127
08/15/2005,670746,23171,562919
09/15/2005,601594,23769,499257
10/15/2005,537107,21057,446620
11/15/2005,517340,22378,421351
12/15/2005,507610,22002,403392
01/15/2006,409802,25032,334607
02/15/2006,429196,23383,350498
03/15/2006,567056,27528,461193
04/15/2006,502403,24994,415797
05/15/2006,578793,27765,480468
06/15/2006,603134,31641,501012
07/15/2006,507408,25796,423143
08/15/2006,557500,31435,460225
09/15/2006,475884,30448,386443
10/15/2006,469092,31648,385751
11/15/2006,432720,36363,349832
12/15/2006,422369,30619,335706
01/15/2007,365297,38993,302488
02/15/2007,372276,34855,308599
03/15/2007,455525,39038,377113
04/15/2007,431043,36892,363764
05/15/2007,473539,42371,401959
06/15/2007,483341,44540,408415
07/15/2007,441046,43735,373058
08/15/2007,446111,48509,375242
09/15/2007,341554,45252,283456
10/15/2007,365869,55746,304820
11/15/2007,333946,57399,274292
12/15/2007,309551,51137,252391
01/15/2008,270806,70554,229161
02/15/2008,289606,66395,245970
03/15/2008,328369,65904,279960
04/15/2008,353531,78510,308293
05/15/2008,375080,81284,328119
06/15/2008,390034,80175,342170
07/15/2008,378648,85689,334255
08/15/2008,363756,83357,321556
09/15/2008,350942,79301,309385
10/15/2008,330164,75568,293867
11/15/2008,252408,67388,222510
12/15/2008,296037,65057,261619
01/15/2009,222048,69380,201462
02/15/2009,247591,77532,224236
03/15/2009,305516,57897,277544
04/15/2009,322308,65778,295160
05/15/2009,335134,78854,305599
06/15/2009,386702,93204,353285
07/15/2009,391393,91153,358731
08/15/2009,361150,77043,329656
09/15/2009,360568,79893,327923
10/15/2009,374886,90766,339969
11/15/2009,342502,77895,305321
12/15/2009,330770,81255,300899
01/15/2010,238132,94309,220064
02/15/2010,261558,81167,241123
03/15/2010,363432,103052,335172
04/15/2010,385535,100984,355852
05/15/2010,381303,95408,350883
06/15/2010,416893,94812,376190
07/15/2010,297810,94574,278054
08/15/2010,313494,98536,291501
09/15/2010,301782,110154,280312
10/15/2010,279117,80204,260114
11/15/2010,270178,67700,250713
12/15/2010,301323,67770,279877
01/15/2011,232283,78998,219762
02/15/2011,236917,64257,223213
03/15/2011,312669,80275,295648
04/15/2011,317720,77881,301463
05/15/2011,332220,76017,315955
06/15/2011,364962,79413,347253
07/15/2011,320199,67812,305785
08/15/2011,352555,74725,337283
09/15/2011,316858,82664,303357
10/15/2011,293425,69684,281407
11/15/2011,279320,73735,267671
12/15/2011,295369,70498,282722
01/15/2012,238417,73051,229405
02/15/2012,267105,65015,256719
03/15/2012,328104,63709,315019
04/15/2012,330508,58175,318258
05/15/2012,369418,65886,356174
06/15/2012,361304,59515,348708
07/15/2012,305613,49700,295448
08/15/2012,227541,35801,219883
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument `tick.number` is really only a suggestion about placing tick marks. In this case, using the `at` argument is likely to produce more consistent results.

If you want to plot every sixth label, first create a vector to index this sequence:

```
okLabs <- seq(1, nrow(inptTrans), by = 6)
okLabs
[1]   1   7  13  19  25  31  37  43  49  55  61  67  73  79  85  91  97 103 109 115
```

Then you can pass `okLabs` to the `at` argument and use it to subset your `labels` (here the `scales` list is assigned to an object that you can pass to the `scales` argument):

```
scalesList <- list(x = list(rot = 45, cex = 1.0,
    labels = format(inptTrans$NotherTime, "%b-%Y")[okLabs], at = okLabs))

barchart (NumE+NumF~ NotherTime, data=inptTrans, main = sprintf("Total")
              ,type='r',xlab = '',ylab='',col=c('red','black')
              ,horizontal=FALSE
              ,scales= scalesList
              ,key=list(text = list(c("Num F","Num E"))
                 ,rectangle=list(col=c('black','red') ),columns = 2
                 ,corner = c(0.05,-0.11),lty = c(1),lwd=3)
              ,stack=TRUE
              )
```

[image]

NOTE that this code won't work well when there are missing (`NA`) values in the data you're trying to plot. For that, you might try omitting the rows with missing data and creating a new `data.frame` from that subset.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that tick.number was only a suggestion (saw that in the manual), but like I said, it had done what I needed before.  But I like your solution, it does exactly what I need.  Thanks a lot!