# how to format properly the x axis with a time variable?

Tags: r, lattice

Consider this simple example

```
tibble(date = seq.Date(from = ymd('2019-01-01'),
                       to = ymd('2019-06-01'), 
                       by = 'days')) %>% 
  mutate(var = rnorm(n())) %>% 
  barchart(var ~ date, data = ., horiz = FALSE)
```

[image]

Here obviously the x axis is messed up. There are too many labels! How can I reduce the number of date ticks?

Ideally one could use the `scales::pretty_breaks()` function like in `ggplot`, but here I was not able to do it even manually:

```
myseq <- seq.Date(from = ymd('2019-01-01'),
                      to = ymd('2019-06-01'), 
                      by = '7 days') 

tibble(date = seq.Date(from = ymd('2019-01-01'),
                       to = ymd('2019-06-01'), 
                       by = 'days')) %>% 
  mutate(var = rnorm(n())) %>% 
  barchart(var ~ date, data = ., horiz = FALSE,
           scales = list(x = list(at = myseq, rot = 45)))
```

simply removes ALL the x labels!!
What do you think? I need a `lattice` solution only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot()` defaults this quite nicely, breaking at months in this case:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tibble(
  date = seq.Date(
    from = ymd('2019-01-01'),
    to = ymd('2019-06-01'), 
    by = 'days')) %>% 
  mutate(var = rnorm(n())) %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(mapping = aes(x = date, y = var))
```

To use lattice, first store your tibble as an object, use a `seq()` to set the intervals (`at`), and then `as.Date()` to set the `labels` and indexing the dates column using the same `seq()`.

```
df1 <- tibble(
  date = seq.Date(
    from = ymd('2019-01-01'),
    to = ymd('2019-06-01'), 
    by = 'days')) %>% 
  mutate(var = rnorm(n()))

df1 %>%
  barchart(var ~ date, data = ., horiz = FALSE,
    scales = 
      list(x = 
        list(
          at = seq(1,152,7),
          labels = as.Date(unlist(df1[,'date']), origin = '1970-01-01')[seq(1,152,7)], 
          rot = 45)
        )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: ha!!! I cant use ggplot my friend. too easy! I want to unleash the powa of `lattice` :)

Comment: I'll come back to this later, currently working on my phone with a crying baby in the arms...

Comment: cool stuff. thanks! do you know if we can use the scales packages directly?

Answer (score 1):

A potential lattice solution based on this: [Decrease number of x-axis ticks (labels) in barchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129580/decrease-number-of-x-axis-ticks-labels-in-barchart)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(lattice)

tb <- tibble(date = seq.Date(from = ymd('2019-01-01'),
                             to = ymd('2019-06-01'), 
                             by = 'days')) %>%
      mutate(var = rnorm(n())) 

dateLabs <- seq(1, nrow(tb), by=7)

scalesList <- list(x = list(rot = 45, labels = format(tb$date, "%b-%d-%Y")[dateLabs], at = dateLabs))

tb %>%
  barchart(var ~ date, 
           data = ., 
           horiz = FALSE,
           scales = scalesList)
```

Comment: very insteresting. any change we can use the scales package directly here?